# Which version of Mac OS X was the first to support RTL (right-to-left) languages?

Tags: macos, language, internationalization

[Apple – Press Info – Mac OS X Hits Stores This Weekend](https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2001/03/21Mac-OS-X-Hits-Stores-This-Weekend.html) (2001) listed seven languages for 10.0. From an archived Apple knowledge base article [Mac OS X 10.6: Changing the direction of text](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH6453) I know that Snow Leopard included support for [right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) *and* bidirectional text. From the knowledge base:

> … When using certain right-to-left writing systems such as Arabic, Hebrew, Yiddish, Persian, Pashto, and Urdu, you may need to quote words from left-to-right writing systems, such as English. When right-to-left text is mixed with left-to-right text, it is called bidirectional text. …

However:

- I can't tell which version of the operating system introduced support for RTL.

[Apple - Mac OS X Snow Leopard - Technical specifications](http://web.archive.org/web/20090612013555/http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html) doesn't list Arabic or Hebrew amongst the languages, so (by implication) whilst *operating system localisations* at that time did not include those languages, the OS did support RTL.

Another archived article, [Hebrew & Arabic Language Kit: System Direction Issues](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA35372), reminds me that for less recent versions of the OS, Apple's installer offered language kits (more recent installers include those languages by default).

---

I tried searching domains such as mellel.com, redlers.com and www.apple.com/pr – e.g. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=languages%20%22Mac%20OS%20X%22%20site:www.apple.com/pr/ – couldn't find an answer.

If it helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellel states that development of Mellel began in 2002 (and I recall Mellel being renowned for RTL support).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was introduced in 10.2, Jaguar, and greatly improved in 10.3, Panther. See [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031202133102780) from MacOSXHints for evidence and more details.

Comment: Thanks! In retrospect, it's odd that none of the following mention language: [Apple Introduces “Jaguar,” the Next Major Release of Mac OS X](https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2002/07/17Apple-Introduces-Jaguar-the-Next-Major-Release-of-Mac-OS-X.html) (2002-07-17); [Apple – Mac OS X – Jaguar](http://web.archive.org/web/20020802214804/http://www.apple.com/macosx/jaguar/); [Apple Announces Mac OS X “Panther”](https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2003/10/08Apple-Announces-Mac-OS-X-Panther.html) (2003-10-08).

Comment: I think they might have been embarrassed that the first versions of OS X were not as capable as either OS 9 or Win XP in this area and did not consider catching up to them as something worth trumpeting.

Answer (score 4):

I think Apple support for RTL may go back to OS 7.1:  See

http://www.macintouch.com/m85_multilingual.html

It was definitely part of OS 9/Classic.  For more info see my old page here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46870715/s/jmlingos9.html

As Mike Scott mentioned, RTL was missing in 10.0 and 10.1.

Comment: OK … reputation to @mike-scott for the strictly correct answer to this question (about Mac OS X) … plus, I'll bounty this answer for satisfying my curiosity about Classic. Incidentally, *Unleash Your Multilingual Mac* is also [in the Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120530165828/http://homepage.mac.com/thgewecke/jmlingos9.html). Thank you both!